# Incrementally increase column letters for SUM formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a KPI sheet where one of the cells need to sum cells in another sheet, depending on which month it is, to create a YTD-value. So for each month this needs to sum another column to the right.

Right now I use a SUM(Sheet2!BE4:BI4) formula which I have to manually drag 1 column to the right each month, so next month it will be SUM(Sheet2!BE4:BJ4)

I've done a cell which retrieves which cell it should use with the following formula which in this case returns the text BI:
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(66);CHAR(68+MID(TEXT($D$18;"DD/MM/YYYY");5;1)))

What I need is, when I change month in the cell "D18" (which is referenced through the CONCATENATE formula), the "BI4" will change. If I increase the month, it will automatically change to "BJ4" and if I decrease the month, it will change to "BH4". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=SUM(Sheet2!$BE$4:BI$4)
```

When you drag this formula across(to right) it will become `=SUM(Sheet2!$BE$4:BJ$4)`, `=SUM(Sheet2!$BE$4:BK$4)` and so on.

You are using **Relative Reference** in your formula. To get get desired result you should use **Absolute Reference** and **Mixed Reference**. See [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html) for details on *cell reference*.

**EDIT:** As per comments

---

Use this formula

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!BE4:"&CONCATENATE(CHAR(66),CHAR(68+MID(TEXT($D$18,"DD/MM/YYYY"),5,1)))&"4"))
```

Note: `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. For details on volatile functions see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm%5C).

Comment: But with absolute/mixed references I will still need to do it manually. I'd like to, when I change month in a cell, the "BI4" will change to BJ4. Will edit it in my question since I now see it isn't fully clear.

Comment: Won't work, does it have something to do with the month (D18, referred to in the CONCATENATE formula) being in Sheet1? I get the error-message at "DD". If I change the formula to:=SUM(INDIRECT(Sheet2!BE4:"&CONCATENATE(CHAR(66);CHAR(68+MID(TEXT($D$18;'DD/MM/YYYY');5;1)))&"4")) - changed " to ', the error marks "4"

Comment: @marreBUS - Is your `Concatenate` formula giving you the desired results?

Comment: @marreBUS - Else try `"'Sheet2'!BE4:"` instead of `"Sheet2!BE4:"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here - that you have your numerical figures on row 4, and in the row above you have the month starting date for that figure.  Similar to the layout below.

[image]

Note: The month names in row 2 are real date values with a custom cell format of `mmm` - it says "Jan" but Excel reads it as 1st January 2017 (or day 42736 if you want to be picky).

With this data in place we can use formula to find the first day of the year and the required day as entered in cell D18.

The formula `DATE(YEAR($D$18),1,1)` will return 1st January for the date entered in cell D18.
To find this date in row 2 we can use `MATCH` to return the column number:
 `MATCH(<date formula>,$2:$2,0)` or `MATCH(DATE(YEAR($D$18),1,1),$2:$2,0)`.

Similarly we can use match to find the end date column number:  `MATCH($D$18,$2:$2,0)`.

Now we need to turn these column numbers into real cell references:
`INDEX(<reference to whole row>,,<column in row to return>)`
`INDEX($4:$4,,<match formula to return column number>)`
`INDEX($4:$4,,MATCH(DATE(YEAR($D$18),1,1),$2:$2,0))` to return first cell reference.
`INDEX($4:$4,,MATCH($D$18,$2:$2,0))` to return last cell reference.

Now all we need to do is stick these together inside a `sum` formula:
`=SUM(<first cell reference>:<second cell reference>)`  or
`=SUM(INDEX($4:$4,,MATCH(DATE(YEAR($D$18),1,1),$2:$2,0)):INDEX($4:$4,,MATCH($D$18,$2:$2,0)))`

Of course, if you don't have the relevant date with your figures then this won't work....